# When entities changes in the blob file saving the file as a new file into cosmosdb

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb

This is my code:

```py
    import logging
    import json
    import os
    from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
    import azure.functions as func

    client = CosmosClient.from_connection_string(os.environ["CosmosDBConnStr"])
    
    database_name = "dmdb"
    container_name = "DataContract"
    
    database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
    container = database.get_container_client(container_name)
    logging.info(f"container: {container}")
    def main(myblob: func.InputStream, doc: func.Out[func.Document]):
        logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                     f"Name: {myblob.name}\n")

 
    contract_data=myblob.read()
    blob_filename = os.path.basename(myblob.name)
    logging.info(f"file name: {blob_filename}")
    logging.info(f"my blob: {myblob}")
    logging.info(f"my document: {doc}")
    doc_value = doc.get()
    logging.info(f"my document1: {doc_value}")
    
    try:
        logging.info(f"contract data: {contract_data}")
        contract_json = json.loads(contract_data)
        version = contract_json.get("version")
        name = contract_json.get("name")
        query = f''' SELECT c.name,c.version
                FROM c 
                '''
        items = list(container.query_items(query, enable_cross_partition_query=True))
        logging.info(f"items: {items}")

        for item in items:
            if item["name"] == name and item["version"] == version:
                logging.info(f"Skipping, item already exists: {item}")
                return
        doc.set(func.Document.from_json(contract_data))
        doc_value = doc.get()
        version = doc_value.get("version")
        name = doc_value.get("name")
        logging.info(f"Version: {version}")
        logging.info(f"Name: {name}")

    except Exception as e:
            logging.info(f"Error: {e}")
```

this is my contract_data:

```json
     {
        "version": "V3",
        "name": "demo_contract9",
        "title": "title1",
        "Theme": "Theme1",
        "description": "test data contract management2",
        "data owner": "aysegul@amsterdam.nl",
        "confidentiality": "open",
        "table1": {
            "description:": "test",
            "attribute_1": {
                "type": "int",
                "description:": "testen",
                "identifiability": "identifiable"
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my cosmos db document:

```json
    {
        "version": "V2",
        "name": "demo_contract9",
        "title": "title1",
        "Theme": "Theme1",
        "description": "test data contract management2",
        "data owner": "j.jansen@amsterdam.nl",
        "confidentiality": "open",
        "table1": {
            "description:": "testen",
            "attribute_1": {
                "type": "int",
                "description:": "testen",
                "identifiability": "identifiable"
            }
        },
        "id": "d4923d64-96df-4de4-baf8-a3e902c86528"
    }
```

With this code i can save the file from blob storage into cosmos db when name and version are different. But when another entities changes in the blob file, i would like to save same file as a new file into cosmos db. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

To uniquely identify a document in Cosmos you need 2 things -

1. id
2. PartitionKey

For each update, if you change the id or partitionKey you get a new document created. Same partition cannot have to documents with same id but same id can exist in another partiton.

Comment: i add this code patch:  for item in items:
            if item["name"] == name and item["version"] == version:
                if item["title"] == title:
                    logging.info(f"Skipping, item already exists: {item}")
                    return  # Skip saving the document
                    container.upsert_item(body=contract_json, pre_trigger_include=None, post_trigger_include=None, partition_key=item["name"])
                    return
 doc.set(func.Document.from_json(contract_data))     but it is not working, how can i regulate it?